# Solve differential equation $3x^3 (y')^2 + 3x^2yy' + 5 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$3x^3 (y')^2 + 3x^2yy' + 5 = 0$

To me it looks like quadratic equation with respect to $y'$, so I came up to that

$$y' = \dfrac{-3x^2y \pm \sqrt{9x^4y^2 - 12x^3}}{6x^3}$$
And from there I got completely stuck. Also I tried to divide everything with $3x^2y'$

$$xy' + y + \dfrac{5}{3x^2y'} = 0$$

I don't know what to do next because of that $3x^2y'$ in the denominator, but $xy' + y$ part looks like Euler equation

Comment: Maple performs $$y(x)=-\frac{2 \sqrt{15}}{3 \mathrm{\sqrt{x}}},y(x)=\frac{2 \sqrt{15}}{3 \mathrm{\sqrt{x}}},y(x)=\frac{(\textit{_}\mathit{C1}^{2} x+20) \sqrt{3}}{6 \textit{_}\mathit{C1} x},y(x)=\frac{(\textit{_}\mathit{C1}^{2}+20 x) \sqrt{3}}{6 \textit{_}\mathit{C1} x}.$$

Comment: Mathematica results in $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to
   -\frac{e^{-\frac{c_1}{2}}
   \left(x+10
   e^{c_1}\right)}{\sqrt{6}
   x}\right\},\left\{y(x)\to
   \frac{e^{-\frac{c_1}{2}}
   \left(x+10
   e^{c_1}\right)}{\sqrt{6}
   x}\right\},\left\{y(x)\to
   -\frac{e^{-\frac{c_1}{2}}
   \left(10
   x+e^{c_1}\right)}{\sqrt{6}
   x}\right\},\left\{y(x)\to
   \frac{e^{-\frac{c_1}{2}}
   \left(10
   x+e^{c_1}\right)}{\sqrt{6}
   x}\right\}\right\} .$$

Comment: Maple makes use of symmetries. Here is a part of the output of `infolevel[dsolve]:=4:`:"* Tackling next ODE.
      *** Sublevel 3 ***
      Methods for first order ODEs:
      --- Trying classification methods ---
      trying homogeneous types:
      trying homogeneous G
      1st order, trying the canonical coordinates of the invariance group
      -> Computing canonical coordinates for the symmetry [0, 1/6/x*(9*x^2*y^2-60*x)^(1/2)]
      <- 1st order, canonical coordinates successful
      <- homogeneous successful".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$xy' + y + \dfrac{5}{3x^2y'} = 0$$
I continue from this line. Change the variable $u=1/x$
$$y'=\dfrac {dy}{d1/x}\dfrac{d1/x}{dx}$$
$$y'=-x^{-2}\dfrac {dy}{d1/x}$$
$$y'=-u^2\dfrac {dy}{du}$$
The ODE becomes:
$$y=uy' + \dfrac{5}{3y'} $$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation)

Comment: Note that in both my reduction and yours, it fits also the d'Alembert equation profile.

Comment: Yes of course @zwim your solution is perfect. I just added mine to show that the Clairaut DE is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $u=xy$ helps eliminating a factor $x^2$ from the ODE.

You get after some simplifications $\quad 3x(u')^2-3uu'+5=0$

Then differentiate to get $(3u'')(2xu'-u)=0$

Which solves to $u=Ax+B$ or $u=C\sqrt{x}$

Since we have only implications here, you need to report in initial ODE to check for spurious solutions and/or adjust coefficients $A,B,C$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some intuition behind differentiation step? Or it's just a sophisticated trick to remember

Comment: It is mostly to cancel the $5$, I noticed I could factor $u'$ without it.